# Nuxt: B-tabs (bootraps-vue) render more 1 tab

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js, render, bootstrap-vue

I have a problem of using [b-tabs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs) with Nuxt.

I'm using b-tabs for displaying tabs, but after refresh, there is 1 more tab is displayed. No problem in local env, but after deployed to prod env, it has problem.

My code:

```html
<b-tabs content-class="mt-5" pills justified>
  <b-tab active title="User Account">
     ...
  </b-tab>
  <b-tab title="User Detail">
     ...
  </b-tab>
  <b-tab title="User Action">
     ...
  </b-tab>
  <b-tab title="User Team">
     ...
  </b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

In this case, the tab `User Account` is duplicated. I just feed unbelievable for this error.

Comment: The issue is clearly not coming from the code that you have shared. Can you add more of it to your question? Especially the part where you do fetch the data. Also, a screenshot may be useful appreaciated. Also the issue is happening in 2 cases: refresh + on production right?

Comment: @kissu Thanks for your reply. I also use axios get request to get data to display inline the tab. But I don't set the number of tabs depend on any params.

Comment: Share some code. Will be faster. :)

Comment: @kissu OK. It's code of my private project, so I will share it for few days.
https://gist.github.com/HoangNK93/ac0137bbd4ee15300b43767edc4be502
Can you view this file?

Comment: I can see it but it would be better if you keep this one private and just reproduced the behavior here, or even host it on codesandbox.